# Is Google Document proposed way of Fragment Creation conflicting with ViewBinding of Fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, android-viewbinding

In [Google Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create#kotlin), we are guided to create Fragment using code as below, where we can pass the layout id through the constructor

```
class ExampleFragment : Fragment(R.layout.example_fragment)
```

At the same time, we know that we are recommended to use ViewBinding to access the view components. As per the [Google Document](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments)

```
private var _binding: ResultProfileBinding? = null
// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root
    return view
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

It feels both will not work together. If one uses ViewBinding as per the [Google Document](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments), one will not able to use the layout ID through constructor as proposed by the [Google Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create#kotlin).

Hence asking here to know if there's a way to get them to work together?

Comment: I've not used that much, but IIRC, there should be a static `bind()` function generated in your `ResultProfileBinding` class that you can use to bind in `onViewCreated()` instead; e.g., `override fun onViewCreated(view: View) { _binding = ResultProfileBinding.bind(view) }`. You wouldn't need to override `onCreateView()`, but ultimately you still have to override something, so you don't really gain anything by using that particular constructor.

Comment: Note that the dev page states "To create a _minimal_ fragment…" (emphasis mine). They aren't necessarily recommending that usage. Indeed, I can think of only a few cases where  it would be useful; e.g., if the `Fragment` is basically just a static display, or if it contains a Navigation setup that can be initialized entirely from the layout and resources, etc.

Comment: Have you considered [not holding onto a reference your binding at all](https://evan.tatarka.me/blog/2020-03-02-you-dont-need-to-null-out-views)?

Comment: Thanks, @ianhanniballake. The reference looks neat, but limited as we will not be able to access our view elsewhere.

Comment: Found another solution https://github.com/FunkyMuse/KAHelpers/tree/master/viewbinding